# Buffer overflow, call a function

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow

I have to override a function's return address using buffer oveflow.

The function itself looks like this(I am passing the name argument):

```
void vuln(char *name)
{
    int n = 20;
    char buf[1024];
    int f[n];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      f[i] = fib(i);
    }
    strcpy(buf, name);
    ...
}
```

I am disassembling it using gdb which gives me the following

```
   0x080485ae <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080485af <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080485b1 <+3>: push   %ebx
   0x080485b2 <+4>: sub    $0x414,%esp
   0x080485b8 <+10>:    mov    %esp,%eax
   0x080485ba <+12>:    mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x080485bc <+14>:    movl   $0x14,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x080485c3 <+21>:    mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
   0x080485c6 <+24>:    lea    -0x1(%eax),%edx
   0x080485c9 <+27>:    mov    %edx,-0x14(%ebp)
   0x080485cc <+30>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x080485cf <+33>:    lea    0x3(%eax),%edx
   0x080485d2 <+36>:    mov    $0x10,%eax
   0x080485d7 <+41>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x080485da <+44>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x080485dc <+46>:    mov    $0x10,%ecx
   0x080485e1 <+51>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x080485e6 <+56>:    div    %ecx
   0x080485e8 <+58>:    imul   $0x10,%eax,%eax
   0x080485eb <+61>:    sub    %eax,%esp
   0x080485ed <+63>:    mov    %esp,%eax
   0x080485ef <+65>:    add    $0x3,%eax
   0x080485f2 <+68>:    shr    $0x2,%eax
   0x080485f5 <+71>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x080485f8 <+74>:    mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
   0x080485fb <+77>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048602 <+84>:    jmp    0x8048621 <vuln+115>
   0x08048604 <+86>:    sub    $0xc,%esp
   0x08048607 <+89>:    pushl  -0xc(%ebp)
   0x0804860a <+92>:    call   0x8048560 <fib>
   0x0804860f <+97>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048612 <+100>:   mov    %eax,%ecx
   0x08048614 <+102>:   mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048617 <+105>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804861a <+108>:   mov    %ecx,(%eax,%edx,4)
   0x0804861d <+111>:   addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048621 <+115>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048624 <+118>:   cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048627 <+121>:   jl     0x8048604 <vuln+86>
   0x08048629 <+123>:   sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x0804862c <+126>:   pushl  0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804862f <+129>:   lea    -0x418(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048635 <+135>:   push   %eax
   0x08048636 <+136>:   call   0x80483c0 <strcpy@plt>
   0x0804863b <+141>:   add    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804863e <+144>:   sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x08048641 <+147>:   lea    -0x418(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048647 <+153>:   push   %eax
   0x08048648 <+154>:   push   $0x80487b7
   0x0804864d <+159>:   call   0x80483a0 <printf@plt>
   0x08048652 <+164>:   add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048655 <+167>:   movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0804865c <+174>:   jmp    0x804867f <vuln+209>
   0x0804865e <+176>:   mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048661 <+179>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
=> 0x08048664 <+182>:   mov    (%eax,%edx,4),%eax
   0x08048667 <+185>:   sub    $0x4,%esp
   0x0804866a <+188>:   push   %eax
   0x0804866b <+189>:   pushl  -0xc(%ebp)
   0x0804866e <+192>:   push   $0x80487c4
   0x08048673 <+197>:   call   0x80483a0 <printf@plt>
   0x08048678 <+202>:   add    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804867b <+205>:   addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0804867f <+209>:   cmpl   $0x13,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048683 <+213>:   jle    0x804865e <vuln+176>
   0x08048685 <+215>:   mov    %ebx,%esp
   0x08048687 <+217>:   nop
   0x08048688 <+218>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
   0x0804868b <+221>:   leave  
   0x0804868c <+222>:   ret
```

The address of the function which should be called with the return of vuln() is 0x804850b. 
How am I supposed to know the amount of fillers until I reach the return address to be overwritten?
I guess the name argument should be in the form "a"*n + "\x0b\x85\x04\x08", where n is some number I am trying to guess. I suppose this should be basic stuff but I am still a beginner so please don't judge me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How am I supposed to know ...

Your code is:

```
0x080485ae <+0>: push   %ebp
0x080485af <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
...
0x0804862f <+129>:   lea    -0x418(%ebp),%eax
0x08048635 <+135>:   push   %eax
0x08048636 <+136>:   call   0x80483c0 <strcpy@plt>
```

Before you enter the function, the return address is at offset `0(%esp)`.

After the first `push`, it's at `4(%esp)`. Since `%esp` is next copied to `%ebp`, it's also at `4(%ebp)`.

Next you see that the location you start copying into is at `-0x418(%ebp)`.

Conclusion: the delta between `&buf[0]` and `&return_address` is `0x418 + 4 == 0x41C`.

Alternative solution: fill `name` input with invalid addresses: `0x01010101`, `0x01010102`, ... `0x010102FF`. Execute the code and *observe* on which address it crashed.

If my calculations are correct, it would crash when `vuln` tries to return to "slot" `0x41C / 4 == 0x107`, which should contain `0x01010208`.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. Now, the return address of vuln() is the address of the function which should be called but I get a segmentation fault before entering the wanted function. I will try to figure the rest out :) Thanks a lot for the good exaplanation!

Comment: @KristiyanTsvetanov My "alternative solution" was flawed (contained `0x00`, which would stop `strcpy`). I fixed it.